# Changing text of buttons to sequential number 0-9

Tags: c#, .net, loops, for-loop, foreach

Writing some code to mimic a pin pad, but ultimately the numbers on the pad should be randomly positioned.

So i have 10 buttons on a form within a panel, and I'm looking to just have them numbered 0-9 to begin with, i currently have the following code, but it seems to start at 1, then go up in 3s

the code i currently have for this is

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
    int i = 0;

    foreach (var item in panel1.Controls)
    {
        if (item is Button)
        {
            var tmp = (Button)panel1.Controls[i];
            tmp.Text = i.ToString();
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

The outcome looks like

[image: Buttons 1 3 5 .. 19]

I cannot understand why it isn't starting at 0 and going up to 9.

Comment: You're counting all controls, not just buttons.  Move the increment inside the `if`. You probably  noticed that in the debugger as you examined the value of `i` and the types of the controls, right?

Comment: There is only buttons within the panel, and if the i++; is moved up into the if it throws a Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.LiteralControl' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button'. error

Comment: Ah, because you also use `i` to index into the array of controls to find the control you already found. Use John Saunders' answer.

Comment: Please ask 2 separate questions - one how to number buttons sequentially (I've edit this one) and new one how to produce random numbers (also it would be better to search for "C# shuffle" instead of asking that).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (item is Button)
{
    ((Button)item).Text = i.ToString();
    i++;
}
```

You already have the button. You don't need to index. Also, i now counts only buttons.

Answer (score -1):

your `i` counts all controls, you need another var to count only Buttons :

```
int j=0;
foreach (var item in panel1.Controls)
        {
            if (item is Button)
            {
                var tmp = (Button)panel1.Controls[i];
                tmp.Text = j.ToString();
                j++;
            }
            i++;
        }
```

Or why won't you try directly:

```
if (item is Button)
{
    item.Text = j.ToString();
    j++;
}
```

Comment: I would get rid of the variable `i` entirely and change the line `var tmp = (Button)panel1.Controls[i];` to `var tmp = item as Button;`

Comment: I would keep the `(Button)` style cast though. The code already checks if `item is Button`, so the additional check that `as Button` does is redundant.